# Fix slow query when checking Number as string

Tags: mysql, wordpress, query-optimization

Wordpress stores both numbers and strings into Users and Posts meta tables. The issue comes when we search for meta_value:

When using a number the query takes 20 times longer then same query and string.

SLOW 0.73 seconds:

```
SELECT * from wp_postmeta AS pm WHERE pm.meta_key = '_customer_user' AND pm.meta_value = 30
```

FAST 0.0013 seconds:

```
SELECT * from wp_postmeta AS pm WHERE pm.meta_key = '_customer_user' AND pm.meta_value = '30'
```

There is a key for each column and combined key. I read it could be a problem with PACK_KEYS, if so than I still do not know how to change it.

**select version();**

```
8.0.31
```

**show create table wp_postmeta;**

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_postmeta` (
 `meta_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `post_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `meta_key` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `meta_value` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
 PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
 KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
 KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191)),
 KEY `postid_key_value` (`post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value`(20)),
 KEY `key_value` (`meta_key`,`meta_value`(20))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4285535 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**Explain SLOW:**

```
SIMPLE  pm  NULL    ref     meta_key,key_value  meta_key    767     const   46930   10.00   Using where
```

**Explain FAST:**

```
SIMPLE  pm  NULL    ref     meta_key,key_value  key_value   1106    const,const     1   100.00  Using where
```

If I cannot fix those indexes in database, than maybe to use some WP filter to fix this kind of queries for Posts' and Users' meta?

**EDIT:**

Since there is no obvious solution, at least for Wordpress we can try and correct similar queries using the query filter this way:

```
function sns_filter_queries( $query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if( stripos($query, $wpdb->postmeta)!==FALSE || stripos($query, $wpdb->usermeta)!==FALSE ) {
        $count = null;
        $query = preg_replace('/meta_value[ ]+=[ ]+(\\d+)/', 'meta_value = \'${1}\'', $query, 1, $count);
    };
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'query', 'sns_filter_queries', 10, 1 );
```

It works fine on my side, hope it may help others.

Comment: Please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `select version();` and `show create table wp_postmeta;` and `explain SELECT ...rest of query` for both queries

Comment: `meta_value` is a LONGTEXT so probably the conversion to an integer is quite circumstantial. Change the database column to `INT` with all frightening consequences.

Comment: No way I can change WP meta values to integer only, lol :) Maybe to use some WP filter to fix this kind of queries for Posts' and Users' meta?

Comment: Can you change the query to compare `...AND pm.meta_value = CONCAT(30)` or `...AND pm.meta_value = CAST(30 AS CHAR)`? Either of those converts the integer to a string.

Comment: @JoopEggen - Unfortunately, WordPress uses a problematical schema design called Entity-Attribute-Value.  All the "values" are stored in a `LONGTEXT` and cannot be changed to `INT`.

Comment: I recommend that you DROP these two redundant/in-the-way indexes:  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
 KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191)),

Answer (score 1):

WordPress's metadata is (as you pointed out) stringly typed: everything's a text string. And, `meta_value` columns, as well as `option_value` columns, are potentially very long strings in `TEXT` column types. The tables were designed this way almost 20 years ago for ultimate flexibility, but this design scales up poorly (as you pointed out).

If you used WordPress's built-in [WP_Meta_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/#accepted-arguments) subsystem to generate the query in your question, you would use something like this.

```php
   $args = [
      'post_type'  => 'post',
      'meta_query' => [
        [
          'key'     => '_customer_user',
          'value'   => 30,
          'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
          'compare' => '=',
        ],
      ],

    ];
    $query  = new \WP_Query( $args );
```

This makes WordPress generate a SQL query something like this.

```sql
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
       wp_posts.*
  FROM wp_posts
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
 WHERE 1=1
   AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
   AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) = '30' 
   AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
   AND (     wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
          OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
 GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
 ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
 LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Obviously suboptimal. (I'm being polite.)

A solution might be to create a virtual column in wp_postmeta, and then index it, like this.

```sql
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD COLUMN meta_value_int INT AS (
       IF(meta_value REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$',CAST(`meta_value` AS SIGNED),NULL)) 
       VIRTUAL;
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD INDEX meta_value_int (meta_value_int);
```

Then a query containing this rewritten WHERE clause could exploit the index.

```sql
   AND wp_postmeta.meta_value_int = 30
```

This solution requires rewriting numeric queries to use the virtual column. That's possible using WordPress's [get_meta_sql](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_meta_sql/) filter. It's conceivable a plugin could do this, adding virtual columns and indexes for all the various datatypes WordPress stashes in those meta_value columns: NUMERIC, BINARY, DATE, DATETIME, DECIMAL, SIGNED, TIME, UNSIGNED.  It sounds like a complex plugin.

It would be nice if it were possible to create and use a function index to speed up access to those stringly typed integers, maybe on `(CAST(meta_value AS SIGNED))`. But that simple expression won't work because of the need to ignore all the `meta_value`s that aren't numbers.

It is possible to create a function index, on MySQL >= 8.0.13 (not on MariaDB), this way.

```sql
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD INDEX meta_int_value 
     ((IF(`meta_value` REGEXP '^[0-9]+$',CAST(`meta_value` AS SIGNED),NULL)));
```

But getting queries to use such an index on a bizarre function is hard.

Comment: Thanks. Those are not my queries, my old friend [WP Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) detected them. Those came from famous [Admin Columns plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/) (pro) on web-store with 40k clients, so you can imagine/calculate 0.7 seconds twice per row, 200 clients on page = disaster :) At the end I aimed similar queries, shall add EDIT above, it may be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

`pm.meta_value` is a *string*; `30` is a number.  Comparing them requires converting the string to a number, which means checking every row without being able to use an `INDEX`.

The other 3 combinations of testing string versus number can work efficiently (that is may be able to use an `INDEX`.)

The solution is to always provide `meta_value` values as strings.

See also this plugin for efficiency in `postmeta`:  [*WP Index Improvements*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)  However, it looks like you have already implemented *similar* indexes.  But...  I suggest that you DROP  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`) and KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191)) since they are redundant and/or in the way.  (The 191 is no longer relevant since you are using Mysql 8.0.)

Comment: it would be nice if you could make an index on `(meta_key,(CAST(meta_value AS UNSIGNED)))` and it would use it, but sadly not

Comment: @ysth - Interesting idea!  Have you tried such?  (Either in WP or in some other application.)

Comment: I did try, with varied cast.  No luck.  MySQL would have to implement this (and document it)

Comment: Thanks, everything is clear. Still cannot change various plugins an easy way (please check the Edit above). The plugin you suggested also looks nice, but it does not cover many of thousands of plugins people use, so I suggest [WP Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) and manual indexing for each slow query. Maybe the combining of those 2 plugins into one would be a bingo, to keep tracking of changes one does.

Comment: @skobaljic - I added a small recommendation.